# Google maps direction api not working for me

Tags: android, api, google-api, google-directions-api

Google Maps Direction API key isn't working for me.
    I want to draw the path between two marker.
    After I used the server key as the api key it worked for the first time but after that it isn't working.

Now its giving me "this ip site or mobile application is not authorized to use this api key" error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Direction api is one of the apis that needs a billing account linked to it [even though its free]

[docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/usage-and-billing)

Comment: no, i think it is free still, some of the mapping api's have you link an account but the service is free [up to some large ] number, 0–100,000